# Graphics2d drawString not working with colored fonts

Tags: java, fonts, graphics2d, emoji, emojione

I am trying to display emojis in swing objects (jLabel, etc) so in order to do so I am using [this library](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java) and the following class so that emojis display just by

```
jLabel.setIcon(new EmojiIcon(":poop:"));
```

Which works with all fonts that have emoji support except for those which are colored (i.e. [EmojiOne](https://www.emojione.com/) and [Noto Color Emoji](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/emoji/))

> What's the point of a monochromatic emoji?

```
public class EmojiIcon implements Icon {
    private Font font;
    private final static int DEFAULT_SIZE = 32;
    private int              width        = DEFAULT_SIZE;
    private int              height       = DEFAULT_SIZE;

    private String emoji;

    public EmojiIcon (String iconString){
        this.emoji = EmojiParser.parseToUnicode(iconString);
        setFont("emojione-android");
        recalculateIconWidth(emoji);
    }

    public void setFont(String strFont){
        try {
            font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("fonts/"+strFont+".ttf")).deriveFont(48f);
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void recalculateIconWidth( String iconString ){
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext( null, true, true );
        Rectangle2D bounds = font.getStringBounds(iconString, frc );
        width = (int) bounds.getWidth();
        height = (int) bounds.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon( Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y ){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setFont( font );
        g2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON );
        g2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );

        g2d.drawString( emoji, 0, height );
    }
}
```

I was looking online wether is it even legal for a font to have a color so i found out [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/64920) that it isn't standarised (at least with .ttf fonts).
Is there a workaround for this? I'd really like to use [EmojiOne font](https://www.emojione.com/)

Comment: Hello! Did you succeed?

Answer (score 0):

this part for load fonts:

```
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path/milibus-rg.ttf")));
```

this for drawing text:

```
    public static BufferedImage textToImage(String text, Font font, int bottomPadding, Color color, BufferedImage background) {
    int width = background.getGraphics().getFontMetrics(font).stringWidth(text);
    int height = background.getGraphics().getFontMetrics(font).getHeight();
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    Graphics2D graphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    graphics.setBackground(new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, .0f)); //transparent
    graphics.setColor(color);
    graphics.setFont(font);
    graphics.drawString(text, 0, height - bottomPadding);
    graphics.dispose();
    return bufferedImage;
}
```